# How to access to different elements of a XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML which contains different information about a flightPlan. I need to take data of this flight plan using "RoutePoints" label. The example below is a pseudocode to represent the structure. The "+" symbol represents that section could expands.

```
    <RoutePoints>
      +<a:anyType z:Id="411" i:type="RoutePointTakeOff">
      +<a:anyType z:Id="472" i:type="RoutePoint">
      +<a:anyType z:Id="518" i:type="RoutePoint">
      <a:anyType z:Ref="349" i:nil="true"/>
      <a:anyType z:Ref="272" i:nil="true"/>
      +<a:anyType z:Id="576" i:type="RoutePoint">
      +<a:anyType z:Id="638" i:type="RoutePointLanding">
    </RoutePoints>
```

Because of I have different type of elements which need to be processing different. I tried to use foreach tool to access this elements, example below:

```
foreach ( var routes in document.Descendants("RoutePoints") ){
    foreach ( var points in routes.Elements() ) {
        if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePoint") {
            //Processing..
        }
        if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePointTakeOff") {
            //Processing..
        }
        if ( points.Attributes(i+"nil").First().Value == "true") {
            //Processing..
        }
        if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePointLanding") {
            //Processing..
        }
    }
}
```

When if clause check the attributes to compare the value and it does not exist, for example, checks value RoutePointTakeOff and it does not exists because this value are in the first row and now is checking on the second row.

I need to take the element, the information that I need to process is inside of elements. For example, inside RoutePoint I need to initialize some attributes with the values ​​that contains. Inside RoutePointTakeOff I need to execute some algorithms. The problem is I need to execute different functionality based on section where pointer is whereas.

I am new programming in C# and I am sure that exists another better forms to access this type of data.

Could you help me to access this data by type?

Comment: "My program crash" - what exactly happens? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: I can't get your XML to parse! Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: @Wheels73 it's invalid. Note the unclosed elements.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann - Ah yes... Still early for me! Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure that `<RoutePoints>` does not have a (default) namespace?  What does the debugger tell you? Also you didn't show how you got `i:`

Comment: The XML is too big, I used a pseudocode to simplify. "+" symbol refers to section could expands (More information).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`, the code is working as intended, every element can be processed:

```
foreach (var routes in document.Descendants("RoutePoints"))
{
    foreach (var points in routes.Elements())
    {
        if (points.Attributes(i + "type").FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "RoutePoint")
        {
        }
        if (points.Attributes(i + "type").FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "RoutePointTakeOff")
        {
        }
        if (points.Attributes(i + "nil").FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "true")
        {
        }
        if (points.Attributes(i + "type").FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "RoutePointLanding")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of `?` as inline null check, if no matching attribute is found.

Comment: When the pointer is in:  <a:anyType z:Ref="349" i:nil="true"/> and check FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "RoutePointTakeOff" the program crash because NullReferenceException was Unhandled.

Comment: No, unless we have different xml files. The `?` operator does not throw.

Comment: Yes, I did not use ? operator. But not works this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "anyType")
                .Select(x => new {
                    id = x.Attributes().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "Id").Select(z => (int)z).FirstOrDefault(),
                    _ref = x.Attributes().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "Ref").Select(z => (int)z).FirstOrDefault(),
                    type = x.Attributes().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "type").Select(z => (string)z).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution takes only the attributes of the XML file and put it in a list, no? I need to take the element, the information that I need to process is inside of elements. For example, inside RoutePoint I need to initialize some attributes with the values ​​that contains.Inside RoutePointTakeOff I need to execute some algorithms. The problem is I need to execute different functionality based on section where pointer is whereas.

Comment: You can add your code to mine.  Use foreach(var route in results){}.  You will need to test for null.  The values will be id, _ref, type.  You did not include any element value in your sample.  If there is a element then add value = (string)x as another line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
public List<DataAttr> GetDataAttribute(XDocument xDocument)
    {
        var dataAttr = new List<DataAttr>();
        foreach (var route in xDocument.Descendants("RoutePoints"))
        {
            foreach (var point in route.Elements())
            {
                if (point.HasElements)
                {
                    dataAttr.AddRange(_getAttributeValues(point.Attributes()));
                }
            }
        }
        return dataAttr;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DataAttr> _getAttributeValues(IEnumerable<XAttribute> attributes)
    {
        return attributes.Select(x => new DataAttr()
        {
            Name = x.Name.LocalName,
            Value = x.Value
        });
    }
public class DataAttr
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

after this one you can sort your data group by name.

if you use of this code, you don't limited in name of attribute.
goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging and finally I found the error...

I was evaluating attribute "type" which not exists in rows 4-5. This led to an error. More specifically:

> NullReferenceException was Unhandled

After all I am using a null control and now it works.

```
foreach ( var routes in document.Descendants("RoutePoints") ){
    foreach ( var points in routes.Elements() ) {
        if ( points.Attributes( i + "type").FirstOrDefault != null ){
             if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePoint") {
                //Processing..
             }
             if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePointTakeOff") {
                //Processing..
             }
             if ( points.Attributes(i+"type").First().Value == "RoutePointLanding") {
                //Processing..
             }
        } else {
             // Will execute this in rows 4-5    
        }
    }
}
```